# Display Table output as a grid of points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, grid-layouts

I want to create a `Grid` or `Plot` (or equivalent) from the following `Table`:

```
Module[{size = 10}, Table[If[PrimeQ[a + b], True], {a, 1, size}, {b, 1, size}]]

(*
{{True, True, Null, True, Null, True, Null, Null, Null, True},
{True, Null, True, Null, True, Null, Null, Null, True, Null},
{Null, True, Null, True, Null, Null, Null, True, Null, True},
{True, Null, True, Null, Null, Null, True, Null, True, Null},
{Null, True, Null, Null, Null, True, Null, True, Null, Null},
{True, Null, Null, Null, True, Null, True, Null, Null, Null},
{Null, Null, Null, True, Null, True, Null, Null, Null, True},
{Null, Null, True, Null, True, Null, Null, Null, True, Null},
{Null, True, Null, True, Null, Null, Null, True, Null, True},
{True, Null, True, Null, Null, Null, True, Null, True, Null}}
*)
```

I want the output to have the following properties:

1. The two 'axes' `a` and `b` are marked, and have ticks at integer values;
2. There is a grid of lines showing integer intervals from both axes;
3. At each intersection with Cartesian coordinates `(a,b)` where the `Table` output is `True`, there should be a `Point`; at `Null` points there should be nothing.

This seems like it should be really simple, but for some reason I can't quite get my head around the syntax...

How do I do it?

Comment: Many thanks for the excellent answers. I have chosen the most general one to mark as answered, but they are all both useful and instructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by @kglr and extending to arbitrary dimensions on the data, this may do what you want:

```
data = Module[{size = 11}, 
  Table[If[PrimeQ[a + b], True], {a, 1, size}, {b, 1, size}]];
With[{elements = Max[Dimensions[data]]}, 
 ListPlot[Position[data, True], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[Large]], Frame -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Range[elements], 
     Thread[{Range[elements], ""}]}, {Range@elements, 
     Thread[{Range[elements], ""}]}}, 
  GridLines -> {Range[elements], Range[elements]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{1, elements}, {1, elements}}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False]]
```

Shown with size set to 11 to show that it fits the generality.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Visualized as squares rather than points

```
ArrayPlot[data,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Range@10, Range@10}, {Range@10, Range@10}},
 DataReversed -> True,
 PlotRangePadding -> None,
 Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How about [`BubbleChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart.html)?

```
tab = With[{n = 10}, PrimeQ @ Array[Plus, {n, n}]];

BubbleChart[Append[1] /@ Position[tab, True], GridLines -> (Range[1, #2] &)];

Labeled[%, {"A", "B"}, {Bottom, Left}]
```

[image]

Adding `FrameTicks -> (Range[1, #2] &)` gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since V 12.2 we can also use [PointValuePlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PointValuePlot.html)

Borrowing `tab` from Mr. Wizard:

```
tab = With[{n = 10}, PrimeQ @ Array[Plus, {n, n}]];

PointValuePlot[
 Thread[Position[tab, True] -> 1],
 GridLines -> All]
```

[image]